# Datable not showing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

datatable is not showing up.
while debugging in firefox code inspector datatable code is shown in grey color.

Javascript code of datatable

```
  $("#kt_datatable_noc").append('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%" id="kt_datatable_noc1"> <thead><tr id="addDTRowHeading"><th>Portfolio Name</th><th>Expiry date</th><th>Expiry days</th></tr></thead></table>');
 
     var dt_table = $("#kt_datatable_noc1").DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searchDelay: 500,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "getNocExpiryDashboardList",
      cache: false,
      data: function (d) {
        d.datat = sendingData();
      },
    },
    lengthMenu: [10, 25],
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    //        "paging": false,
    ordering: false,
    searching: false,
    //        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    columns: [
      {  data: "portfolioName", width: "33%", className: "word-break" },
      {  data: "toDate" , width: "33%"},
      {  data: "datediff" , width: "33%"},
     
      
    ],
  });
  
}
```

html code of datatable div

`<div class="kt-datatable display" id="#kt_datatable_noc"></div>`

data returned by json object by request

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            
            "toDate": "2021-09-16",
            
            "portfolioName": "abc",
            "datediff": "-133",
            
        },
        {
        
            "toDate": "2021-09-16",
            
            "portfolioName": "asb",
            "datediff": "-133",
            
        }
    ],
    "sEcho": 0,
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2
}
```

datatable is not showing up.
firefox code inspector datatable code is shown in grey color.